# ¿Los métodos que puede usar un objeto sólo son los que se han definido en la instancia de dicho objeto?

Tags: java, poo

Resulta que estoy comenzando a aprender acerca de POO y me surgió está duda:
¿los métodos que puede usar un objeto son únicamente los declarados en su clase?
¿existe una manera para que un objeto use métodos no declarados en su clase?

Gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: Podrías colocar un ejemplo de lo que estas haciendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los métodos que puede llamar un objeto Java **son los que están declarados en su propia clase**, pero **también podrá llamar métodos que herede.**

Te dejo un ejemplo:

**Clase DosDimensiones**

```
//Clase para objetos de dos dimensiones
class DosDimensiones{
    double base;
    double altura;
    void mostrarDimension(){
        System.out.println("La base y altura es: "+base+" y "+altura);
    }
}
```

**Clase triangulo que extiende de DosDimensiones**

```
//Una subclase de DosDimensiones para Triangulo
class Triangulo extends DosDimensiones{
    String estilo;
    double area(){
        return base*altura/2;
    }
    void mostrarEstilo(){
        System.out.println("Triangulo es: "+estilo);
    }
}
```

**Clase Lados3 desde donde llamo un metodo de DosDimensiones a traves de un objeto de la clase triangulo**

```
class Lados3{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangulo t1=new Triangulo();
        Triangulo t2=new Triangulo();
        t1.base=4.0;
        t1.altura=4.0;
        t1.estilo="Estilo 1";
        t2.base=8.0;
        t2.altura=12.0;
        t2.estilo="Estilo 2";
        System.out.println("Información para T1: ");
        t1.mostrarEstilo();
        t1.mostrarDimension();
        System.out.println("Su área es: "+t1.area());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Información para T2: ");
        t2.mostrarEstilo();
        t2.mostrarDimension();
        System.out.println("Su área es: "+t2.area());
    }
}
```

Explicación:

Para resumir como veras la clase `DosDimensiones` tiene el metodo `mostrarDimension()` que es llamado desde la clase `Lados3` a traves de un objeto de la clase `Triangulo`, ya que esta extiende de la clase `DosDimensiones`, **heredando sus metodos y atributos.**

Fuera de esto tambien es necesario hablar de la palabra `static`; una clase, método o campo declarado como estático puede ser accedido o invocado sin la necesidad de tener que instanciar un objeto de la clase. Uno de los ejemplos típicos de uso de métodos y variables estáticas es la clase java.lang.Math:

```
public class MathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double floorOfPi = Math.floor(Math.PI);
        System.out.println(floorOfPi);
    }
}
```

Mas info sobre herencia, POO y static:

http://sepwww.stanford.edu/data/media/public/sep/jon/family/jos/oop_es/oop1.htm
http://profesores.elo.utfsm.cl/~agv/elo330/2s05/lectures/JAVA/Herencia_en_Java.html
https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/09/17/la-directiva-static-en-java/

**Tal vez me explaye demasiado, pero espero que te sirva!**

Answer (score 0):

SI.

Pero hay un pero.

Si declaras una instancia de otro objeto dentro de la instancia de tu objeto, podrias usar sus metodos.

Si el objeto es estatico (static en la mayoria de los lenguajes), podrias usar sus metodos.

Entonces la respuesta seria no, pero como tienen que ocurrir otras cosas para que pudieras usar metodos que no definiste en tu clase, la respuesta es Si, solo podes usar los metodos que definiste en tu clase.

---

A bajo nivel pasa lo siguiente. Un objeto es una estructura en memoria definida por el compilador, con punteros a diferentes lugares donde se guardaran los metodos (funciones) y las definición de las variables (propiedades).

Cuando en tu sistema definis una instancia del objeto, por lo general el compilador lo que hace alli es guardar un puntero que va a contener una copia de la estructura de memoria que se definio antes. Por lo tanto, hay una posición de memória para cada metodo. Si estuvieras parado dentro de un objeto, no tenes forma de saber la posición de memória de otro objeto. Por lo tanto, no podes acceder a dicho metodo.

Los metodos estaticos "serían" la excepción a esta regla, ya que estan en un lugar de memoria que puede ser accedido por cualquiera.

Tengamos en cuenta que todo esto esta regido por las leyes del compilador.. si uno pudiera irse a bajo nivel, podria hacer trampa y si sabe en que posicion esta un metodo ejecutarlo.. pero todo eso seria como "hackear" el sistema...